# Linq to SQL Random Timeouts on Simple Small Queries

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I have a rather unique problem. I have a local database `DatabaseModel.mdf` that utilizes linq to sql classes. Sometimes, randomly, I will get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=26; handshake=11; [Login] initialization=4; authentication=4; [Post-Login] complete=1007;  '

Here is a minimal isolation of the code that's involved:

```cs
public class Universe : RepositoryObject
{
    public int ID { get; private set; } = -1;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static List<Universe> All()
    {
        using (LinqModelDataContext context = new LinqModelDataContext(Model.DatabaseConnection))
        {
            List<Universe> universes = new List<Universe>();
            foreach (UniverseModel model in context.UniverseModels)
            {
                Universe universe = PopulateUniverse(model);
                if (!(universe is null)) { universes.Add(universe); }
            }
            return universes.Count == 0 ? null : universes;
        }
    }

    public override void Save()
    {
        using (LinqModelDataContext context = new LinqModelDataContext(Model.DatabaseConnection))
        {
            UniverseModel model = context.UniverseModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == this.ID);
            if (model is null)
            {
                model = new UniverseModel()
                {
                    Name = this.Name
                };
                context.UniverseModels.InsertOnSubmit(model);
            }
            else
            {
                model.Name = this.Name;
            }

            context.SubmitChanges();
            this.ID = model.Id;         //! Gives back the ID that SQL assigned to the record.
            this.IsSaved = true;
        }
    }

    private static Universe PopulateUniverse(UniverseModel model)
    {
        if (model is null) { return null; }
        return new Universe()
        {
            ID = model.Id,
            Name = model.Name
        };
    }
}
```

And then the Unit Test:

```cs
    [TestMethod]
    public void AllMethodProperlyReturnsAllInstances()
    {
        // Arrange
        Model.PopulateDatabaseConnection(GlobalTestData.TestingDirectory);
        List<Universe> universes = new List<Universe>();
        universes.Add(new Universe() { Name = "Test1" });
        universes.Add(new Universe() { Name = "Test2" });
        universes.Add(new Universe() { Name = "Test3" });

        // Act
        universes.ForEach(x => x.Save());
        List<Universe> returnUniverses = Universe.All();

        // Assert
        foreach (Universe universe in universes)
        {
            if (!returnUniverses.Any(x => x.ID == universe.ID)) { Assert.Fail(); }
        }
    }
```

I don't want to resort to setting the command timeout because the connection shouldn't take this long on 10 records to begin with. I've scoured the internet and SO for months trying to find someone that has had the same problem before I post, to no avail. Anyone got any ideas?

### Update

So I've narrowed the problem a bit, It seems to only happen in debug mode. If I run the unit test, it works fine, but if I debug the unit test, sometimes I'll get the error and sometimes I won't. Maybe that will help a little.

Comment: Did you try to run your code on different PCs?

Comment: Yes, this has been ongoing since I had an older computer. I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Try to install SQL Server Express (it's free) and check this issue on it. It really looks like a bug, but it will be great to find out a source of the problem.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the queries. The error says it can't even login, much less execute any queries. What is the connection timeout? What does the connection string look like?

Comment: What is the *full exception*, including the call stack? This will show where the error was thrown.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `DatabaseConnection = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
                "AttachDbFilename=" + Path.Combine(directory, "DatabaseModel.mdf") +
                ";Integrated Security=True";`

Comment: @Miamy I will try that and see what I find.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://pastebin.com/5AdvP4yC for the full stack trace. Inner Exception is a Win32 Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some sessions of hair-pulling and deep thought, I figured out the solution to my problem. I'm answering my own question just in case anyone else comes across this issue, they won't have to go through what I went through.

I noticed that setting a break point on the `Save` method made the issue more likely:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void AllMethodProperlyReturnsAllInstances()
{
    // Arrange
    Model.PopulateDatabaseConnection(GlobalTestData.TestingDirectory);
    List<Universe> universes = new List<Universe>();
    universes.Add(new Universe() { Name = "Test1" });
    universes.Add(new Universe() { Name = "Test2" });
    universes.Add(new Universe() { Name = "Test3" });

    // Act
    universes.ForEach(x => x.Save()); // <-- Break Point Here
    List<Universe> returnUniverses = Universe.All();

    // Assert
    foreach (Universe universe in universes)
    {
        if (!returnUniverses.Any(x => x.ID == universe.ID)) { Assert.Fail(); }
    }
}
```

Then it hit me: What if the problem is not caused by the code, but the debugging itself? Like I said the problem disappeared when I wasn't debugging, almost like a reverse heisenbug. So I tested it. I ran the unit test in debug mode with the break point over and over again in quick succession to try and reproduce the issue. No errors. Ran it one more time, and then stepped away from the computer. Came back and when I continued the debug session from the break point the error surfaced.

Then I ran the unit test and intentionally waited at that break point for 30 seconds. **It threw the exception every time without fail.**

So basically it was an assumption on my part that if the code is halted and you have a connection open, the timer stops. **It does not. The timer was timing out during halt, and then when I continued the session, it already had the exception waiting for me.** This was really a surprise to me, and something that I didn't even think of, because I could find nothing on the internet or documentation that states this as expected behavior.

I hope this helps anyone who runs into this issue.

Comment: The default connection timeout is 30 seconds so if you wait for more than 30 seconds with a user-instance database (essentially an embedded database) you'll exceed that timeout. You wouldn't get that trying to connect to a server

Comment: Well yes i knew that much, the issue being I had no idea that stepping through the code and causing a breakpoint doesnt pause the timer

Comment: Neither did I until you explained that you use a User Instance database. That feature is deprecated since 2008 R2. The embedded database scenario is covered by LocalDB now. In other cases, if you install SQL Server Express, why not *use* it as a database server too? In multi-tenant environments and hosting it's *far* better to use a [partially contained database](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2013/02/26/sql-server-2012-partially-contained-databases-part-1-contained-logins/) per tenant than install a separate Express instance per client

Comment: I **am** using LocalDB. I am not using SQL Server Express. The individual databases are actually used in the application to store project information. The application makes "projects" kind of in the same vein as visual studio, and most of the data is persisted in an individual database in that project folder.